# parse push notifications from client to everyone else

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform

I'm currently setting up push notifications in my mobile app, using parse.com.  I have it working so when something is done on the client, a push notification is created and sent out on a channel everyone is subscribed to.

The only problem is, I don't want the client who generated the push notification to get the push notification. I think I need to do something like this:

```
ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
pushQuery.whereEqualTo("channels", "Everyone"); 
pushQuery.whereNotEqualTo("user", thisDevice);
```

But I can't figure out the correct way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation found here:

https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-queries/Android

The first step is to store a reference to the current user in your Installation, if you haven't already:

```
// Associate the device with a user
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.put("user",ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
installation.saveInBackground();
```

Once that is done you can then follow the next section where you push using a query (assuming you're doing client-side pushes):

```
// Create our Installation query
ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
pushQuery.whereEqualTo("channels", "Everyone");
pushQuery.whereNotEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

// Send push notification to query
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(pushQuery); // Set our Installation query
push.setMessage("Hello world!");
push.sendInBackground();
```

Comment: Thanks! That was what I needed ... also needed this line though:       ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();